# Transfer format from XSLT into xml file

Tags: c#, c#-3.0

I'm using C#.net to create a simple web page that plays mp3 by loading from SQL server to XML but I have a problem with the format of XML and dewplayer-playlist.swf, so I want to format XML when I load from SQL server using Dataset to write XML to simple XML work with dewplayer-playlist.swf.

**using C# to format XML :**

---

```
    System.Xml.Xsl.XslCompiledTransform proc = new      System.Xml.Xsl.XslCompiledTransform();
    proc.Load(Server.MapPath("person.xslt"));

    proc.Transform(Server.MapPath("person.xml"), Server.MapPath("playlist_1.xml"));
```

---

**File :person.xslt**

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
 <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
    <playlist version="1" xmlns="http://xspf.org/ns/0/">
        <trackList>
            <xsl:for-each select="NewDataSet">
                <track>

                    <title>
                        <xsl:value-of select="title"/>
                    </title>

                    <location>
                        <xsl:value-of select="location"/>
                    </location>
                    <album>
                        <xsl:value-of select="album"/>
                    </album>
                    <creator>
                        <xsl:value-of select="creator"/>
                    </creator>
                    <sGroupID>
                        <xsl:value-of select="sGroupID"/>
                    </sGroupID>

                </track>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </trackList>
    </playlist>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

**File :person.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<NewDataSet>
    <track>
        <title>La Symphonie du Nouveau Monde</title>
        <location>https://knalga.dm1.livefilestore.com/y2pAzwGFwh3A9xw86yCUf4OuRcubbLkETnkpoycw0uwV3X5h7vYjsGkSRKPBkTSjYCwfthltxwCBcwkesFK0SI9VVFdr_4tmwlSryMGpLDTpZg/SoundCloud%20Widget.mp3</location>
        <album>1</album>
        <creator>1</creator>
        <sGroupID>1</sGroupID>
    </track>
    <track>
         <title>La Symphonie</title>
         <location>https://knyt1a.dm1.livefilestore.com/y2pvBPjLD16FTVOPyeZMU38KjzPr_mqqKj7RpvNizbkITULnctUcpwk_YAP89OB2-sNMA8eMRgnf0RtzfO-vL8ViGmwSBnQ20W75I11UMigmS8/05%20M.O.P%20-%20You%20Know%20You%20Love%20This%20%5Bprod.%20Lil%20Fame%5D.mp3</location>
         <album>1</album>
         <creator>1</creator>
         <sGroupID>1</sGroupID>
    </track>
</NewDataSet>
```

---

**The Result I want to be the File of playlist_1.xml like this**

---

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <playlist version="1" xmlns="http://xspf.org/ns/0/">


  <trackList>



      <track>
        <location>mp3/test2.mp3</location>
        <creator>Antonin Dvorak</creator>
        <album>La Symphonie du Nouveau Monde</album>
         <title>La Symphonie du Nouveau Monde</title>
        <annotation></annotation>
        <duration></duration>
         <image>covers/2.jpg</image>
        <info></info>
        <link>http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cesaria_Evora</link>
    </track>

    <track>
        <location>mp3/test3.mp3</location>
        <creator>Jean-Claude Petit</creator>
         <album>Le Hussard sur le Toit</album>
        <title>Le Hussard sur le Toit</title>
        <annotation></annotation>
        <duration></duration>
        <image>covers/3.jpg</image>
        <info></info>
                        <link>http://fr.wikipedia.org                    /wiki/Le_Hussard_sur_le_toit_%28film%29</link>
    </track>


</trackList>
 </playlist>
```

**How can I do this code with # ?**